# Get Postgres function SELECT result back as composit type or Json Array

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, function, spring-boot, hikaricp

Entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "myversion")
@Table(name = "myversion", schema = "public")
public class MyVersion
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "version")
    String version;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    Date timestamp;

    @Column(name = "tablesrenamed")
    @Convert(converter = TablesRenamedConverter.class)
    List<TableRenamed> tablesRenamed;
}
```

Created postgres table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.myversion
(
    version character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    tablesrenamed json[],
    CONSTRAINT myversion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (version)
)
```

Need to use a postgres function to select and return row with max timestamp. But none working:

1. Use SQL SELECT in Postgres function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getmyversionsql()
    RETURNS myversion
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
    SELECT * FROM public.myversion
        WHERE timestamp=(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM public.myversion);
$BODY$;
```

```java
StoredProcedureQuery queryMyVersionSQL = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("public.getmyversionsql", MyVersion.class);
        if (queryMyVersionSQL.execute())
        {
            MyVersion myversion1 = (MyVersion) queryMyVersionSQL.getSingleResult();
```

Error:

> Session/EntityManager is closed

2. Use plpgsql function and put SELECT result as OUT parameter:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getmyversionout(OUT myversionout myversion)
    RETURNS myversion
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT version INTO myversionout
        FROM public.myversion WHERE timestamp=(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM public.myversion);
END;
$BODY$;
```

```java
StoredProcedureQuery queryMyVersionOUT = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("public.getmyversionout", MyVersion.class).registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, MyVersion.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
if (queryMyVersionOUT.execute())
{
  MyVersion myversion1 = (MyVersion) queryMyVersionOUT.getOutputParameterValue("myversionout");
```

Error:

> Type cannot be null

3. Use plpgsql function with REF_CURSOR:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getmyversionrefcursor()
    RETURNS refcursor
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    myversions refcursor;           -- Declare cursor variables                         
BEGIN
    OPEN myversions FOR 
        SELECT * FROM public.myversion
            WHERE timestamp=(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM public.myversion);
    RETURN myversions;
END;
$BODY$;
```

```java
StoredProcedureQuery queryMyVersion = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("public.getmyversionrefcursor", MyVersion.class).registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, void.class,ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
if (queryMyVersion.execute())
{
  // MyVersion myversion1 = (MyVersion)_queryMyVersion.getSingleResult();
  List<MyVersion> myversions = queryMyVersion.getResultList();
```

Error:

> Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults

How could I invoke Postgres function and get SELECT row result back?

Comment: Perhaps you want to tag the framework you are using. SQL part seems to be okay.

Comment: You don't need to wrap code snippets with embedded code runner since they're not able to run.